# How to monitor CPU and memory usage in Windows Server 2008

Tags: memory-management, windows-server-2008, cpu-usage, performance-monitor

I am new to Windows servers and I'm using Windows Server 2008.

I have to monitor CPU usage and memory usage in percentage.

I am using performance monitor for that but there are lop many options under CPU and Memory section I am confused which option I need to select to get CPU and memory usage.

Comment: You need to give us more information: How are you going to use the data? Do you need to dump the data to a file for later analysis? Are you writing your own program to monitor it? Or do you just want a convenient too to look at the usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. No need for external software.

In "Start -> Administrative tools-> Performance monitor" we need to set %CPU and committed bytes and it starts displaying a graphical report.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Ideally with a couple of screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

I've being using windows server along many years using the *task manager* and the **resource monitor** (under the *performance* tab) to check, detect or fix any matter related with network, CPU, memory or disk input/output.

For historical reports regarding usage you've to record into a third party application configuring the *SNMP service*.